# Flutter Connection State Management

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello I am doing my fist App in Flutter and i am just setting up the authentication with FireBase, and a mistake its happenning. Im trying to manage the state and navigate between Home and Login with the streambuilder, and its working fine but only if i do a hot restart on Android Studio after registering a new user. After the hot reload it works fine, i am able to login with any of the existing users and it navigates to the home screen, and when i log out goes back to login screen, but if i create new user than just stops working, the screens do not alterate anymore when i log in with any of the old users...

here its my main

```
 class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
 // This widget is the root of your application.
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return MaterialApp(
       debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
       theme: ThemeData(primaryColor: cPrimary),
       home: StreamBuilder(
         stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
         builder: (context, snapshot) {
           if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active){
             if(snapshot.hasData){
               return Home_Screen();
             } else if (snapshot.hasError){
               return Center(child: Text('${snapshot.error}'),);
             }
           } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
             return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(color: cPrimary,));
           }
           return LoginScreen();
         }
         )
     );
 }
}
```

Here is my login and register functions

```
//Sign Up
Future <void> signUp({
  required String email,
  required String password,
  required String username,
}) async {
  try {
    if(email.isNotEmpty && password.isNotEmpty && username.isNotEmpty){
    UserCredential userCredential = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email,
        password: password,

    );
    //add user to database
    await _firestore.collection('users').doc(userCredential.user!.uid).set({
      'username' : username,
      'email' : email,
      'uid' : userCredential.user!.uid,
    });
    }

  } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
    if (e.code == 'weak-password') {
      print('The password provided is too weak.');
    } else if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
      print('The account already exists for that email.');
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
}
//Log In
  Future <void> logIn({
    required String email,
    required String password,
  }) async {
    try {
      if(email.isNotEmpty && password.isNotEmpty ){
        UserCredential userCredential = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email,
          password: password,
          );}
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
        print('No user found for that email.');
      } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
        print('Wrong password provided for that user.');
      }
    }
  }
```

and here its how i am calling the functions on my screens

```
ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  setState(() {
                    _isLoading = true;
                  });
                  await AuthService().logIn(
                      email: _emailController.text,
                      password: _passwordController.text,);
                  setState(() {
                    setState(() {
                      _isLoading = false;
                    });
                  });
                  },

ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              setState(() {
                _isLoading = true;
              });
              await AuthService().signUp(
                email: _emailController.text,
                password: _passwordController.text,
                username: _usernameController.text,
              );
              setState(() {
                _isLoading = false;
              });
```

Answer (score 0):

After creating the user account, ensure you log in as well.

```dart
//Sign Up
Future <void> signUp({
  required String email,
  required String password,
  required String username,
}) async {
  try {
    if(email.isNotEmpty && password.isNotEmpty && username.isNotEmpty){
    UserCredential userCredential = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email,
        password: password,

    );
    //add user to database
    await _firestore.collection('users').doc(userCredential.user!.uid).set({
      'username' : username,
      'email' : email,
      'uid' : userCredential.user!.uid,
    });
    }

    // add this
    await logIn(email: email, password: password);
  } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
    if (e.code == 'weak-password') {
      print('The password provided is too weak.');
    } else if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
      print('The account already exists for that email.');
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank You for the tip, it makes sense. But the problem that was hapenning kept hapenning, i was going manually to the login screen before and logging in, so the same issua happens loggin in in the same function as registering.